# Re-instantiating a Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the following code, could anyone please clarify my doubt below.

```
public static void Main() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(Display);
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);     
    // Throws exception, thread is terminated, cannot be restarted. 
    thread.Start() 
}

public static void Display() {

}
```

It seems like in order to restart the thread I have to re-instantiate the thread again. Does this means I am creating a new thread? If I keep on creating 100 re-instiation will it create 100 threads and cause performance issue?

Comment: You might want to enqueue `Display` so it gets handled by the thread-pool instead of manually creating a thread.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Normally you avoid the thread creation overhead by leaving threads in an idle state, blocking, and then start them up again when you have more work. But really, what is your actual problem?

Comment: There is a difference between, thread and Thread. In the above code, you are starting the thread "thread" twice. The Sleep method that you are calling does not invoke the thread that you have started, but applications main thread

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just provided an example. Its not the actual code. Just want to know whether it creates a new thread or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you either have to create a new thread or give the task to the thread pool each time to avoid a genuinely new thread being created.  You can't restart a thread.

However, I'd suggest that if your task has failed to execute 100 times in a row, you have bigger problems than the performance overhead of starting new tasks.

Comment: Ok Thanks John. If I want to execute the same method many times I need to add it to the thread pool queue again and again?

Comment: @Bharskar: Or just change the structure so that you loop *within* the thread until it works... have a method which calls Display multiple times from the same new thread, instead of a new thread for *each* call.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to start the thread after `sleep`, the thread wake up automatically. It's the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you can't start the thread if it has already started. In your example, thread has finished it is work, that's why it is in terminated state.

you can check status using:
    Thread.ThreadState

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to wake the thread up before the 5 seconds in complete? In which case you could try using Monitor (Wait, Pulse etc)